# How can we check the Country Specific Domain's email through Regex

Tags: php, regex, validation

I would like to know the proper regex which allows me to remove specific email domains from the list. Example: `gmail.com`, `hotmail.com`, `.co.in`, `aol.com`, `yahoo.com`, `.gov`, `.edu`, etc.

I just want to filter the results through PHP Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want something like this:

```
//$yourFilterList can be array containing gmail.com, hotmail.com , etc
foreach($emails as $key => $email) {
    $checkFor = array_pop(explode("@", $email));
    if(in_array($checkFor, $yourFilterList)) {
        unset($email[$key]);
    }
}
//Again do you mean sorting
sort($emails);
```

Comment: yes it solved 90% problem, but i m looking for a code in which we can sort the whole list of pure emails. except gmail.com, hotmail.com, .co.in, aol.com, yahoo.com, .gov, .edu, etc. at once.

Comment: see edited code, do you mean sorting the emails after filtering out unwanted mails..?

Comment: if(in_array($checkFor, $yourFilterList)) {
        unset($email[$key]);
in this match code. we can not match the multiple values, there is rigidity to match only single item one by one. it will take more time to check the 5000 emails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, but if you're trying to get rid of certain domains from the email address:

```
$email = preg_replace(array(
    "/gmail.com/",
    "/hotmail.com/",
    "/.co.in/",
    "/aol.com/",
    "/yahoo.com/"), "", $email);
```

Or if you're trying to get rid of the domain you could do

```
$email = preg_replace("/@.*?$/", "", $email);
```